# method to convert from a string to an int

Tags: java, string, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting string to int in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java)

I am trying to write a method that returns an `int` from a `String` variable.
My method is:

```
public int returnInt(String s) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Integer.valueOf(String)` for this

Comment: Thanks heiko  but i am trying to write a method to use .

Comment: @logic101 - Since you want to write the method itself, I assume it is homework. Read this post about [how to ask homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)